# Could we use data.table setorder by group?

Tags: r, data.table

Simple question :

I want to use `data.table::setorder` on my DT, but I can not do this by group.
Is it possible ?

In this example, I order my whole DT :

```
DT = data.table(a=rep(c('C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'E'), each = 4), b=sample(1:1000,20))
setorder(DT, b)
DT
```

But I want to keep a fixed.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks, but it is not what I need. The order of my column 'a' must not be changed, and stay C C C C A A A A...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to get as end result, 
maybe 
`DT[,setorder(.SD,b),by=a]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like below?

```
> DT[, .SD[order(b)], a]
    a   b
 1: C 129
 2: C 679
 3: C 836
 4: C 930
 5: A 270
 6: A 299
 7: A 471
 8: A 509
 9: D 187
10: D 307
11: D 597
12: D 978
13: B 277
14: B 494
15: B 874
16: B 950
17: E 330
18: E 591
19: E 775
20: E 841

> DT[, setorder(.SD, b), a]
    a   b
 1: C 129
 2: C 679
 3: C 836
 4: C 930
 5: A 270
 6: A 299
 7: A 471
 8: A 509
 9: D 187
10: D 307
11: D 597
12: D 978
13: B 277
14: B 494
15: B 874
16: B 950
17: E 330
18: E 591
19: E 775
20: E 841
```

Comment: It's exactly that !! Thank you very much !!

Comment: It might be more efficient to do the ordering ahead of the by call for some datasets. e.g., `dt[order(b), .SD, a]`. +1.

Comment: Wouahou it's very technical and very precise, I learn from it day after day, many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option:

```
DT[order(rleid(a), b)]
```